# Extremely slow CNN

Tags: keras, cnn

I am trying to train a CNN with keras in R. I have a time series that is 3-dimensional, so every sample has dimensions 95 x 365 and has 80 features, which I feed in as channels. The output is only 1 value. The problem is that the net is extremely slow. Training the net for only 1 epoch with 400 samples takes 33  minutes. The architecture is very simple (I actually had a deeper net but since it was so slow I simplified  it to see if that helps):

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
    model %>% 
      layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(9, 9), activation = "relu",
                    input_shape = c(95, 365, 80)) %>%
      layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = 2) %>%
      layer_flatten() %>%
      layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu") %>%
      layer_dense(units=1)

    model %>% compile(
      loss = 'mse',
      optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop()
    )

    model %>% fit(
      x_train, y_train,
      batch_size = 32,
      epochs = 1,
      verbose = 0
    )
```

I really do not know what the issue is. I trained simpler networks such as MLPs and the computational time was in a "normal" range, like a few minutes for e.g. 100 epochs. So I guess the problem is not in the hardware I use.

Comment: The network you define above has quite a lot of parameters (which you can check using `summary(model)`) given that the input shape is `(95, 365, 80)` and you are using only 1 convolutional layers and 1 pooling layer. One way to decrease the number of parameter would be to increase the number of convolutional and pooling layers in your network.

Answer (score 0):

As CNN is computation expensive because of matrices calculation that's the point were GPU helps and when you perform the same operation on CPU it takes a lot of time as the number of core in CPU is far less than GPU.

As your data represented in 95x365 with 80 channels in them, the matrices operation making it slow

Comment: I guess it is a dumb quesstion, but how can I use GPU? Or how do I know which one I am using?

Comment: In the case of keras, you don't have to manually set GPU usage if GPU is available it starts using it.

Comment: @msloryg That is not true, you need to have tensorflow-gpu installed in order to take advantage of your GPU

Answer (score 0):

If youre local environment is slowing down your training try using an online platform that provides you with free GPU's like [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com), [Kaggle's Free GPU's](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/running-kaggle-kernels-with-a-gpu)

These are a few [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8zToZa7h0) to use the same.